# Installing node with nvm in sudo user

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04

how to install node with **nvm** in **sudo** user and so that every other user can 
use that installed node from sudo user only not by installing again by any other user

Answer (score -1):

you can use below commands to install node js  using nvm. assuming you have already installed the NVM.

> > nvm ls

it will give you available node js version.

> > nvm install 8.12.0

it will install node version 8.12.0

> > nvm use 8.12.0

it will set node  current node version to 8.12.0

> > nvm alias default 8.12.0

it will set node version to default .

Comment: im not asking about default node.im asking about how to make install in sudo user and make it to use that node only by all the users